# PLSQL trigger - update records based on select query

Tags: plsql, triggers

I have three tables:

```
HouseMode:
mode_id (INT, PK)
switch (CHAR 1BYTE)

ModeDevices:
modedevice_id (INT, PK)
house_mode (INT, FK)
houseroomdevice (INT, FK)

HouseRoomDevices:
houseroomdevice_id (INT, PK)
switch (CHAR 1BYTE)
```

I would like to have a trigger which updates switches from `HouseRoomDevices` table after updating switch in `HouseMode` table.
My trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER switch
BEFORE UPDATE
ON HouseMode
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE houseroomdevices
  SET switch = :NEW.switch
  WHERE EXISTS(SELECT houseroomdevice_id FROM houseroomdevices INNER JOIN modedevices ON houseroomdevice = houseroomdevice_id WHERE house_mode = :NEW.mode_id);
END;
```

But when I try to update record:

```
UPDATE HouseMode
SET switch = 1
WHERE mode_id = 1;
```

It updates all records from `HouseRoomDevices` table.

Comment: Believe it should be AFTER UPDATE ON HouseMode as per your statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update statement is wrong, because your WHERE condition is always true. Use this one:

```
UPDATE houseroomdevices
SET switch = :NEW.switch
WHERE houseroomdevice_id IN  (SELECT houseroomdevice FROM modedevices WHERE house_mode = :NEW.mode_id);
```

Comment: Pavel, that's a wrong syntax. You will have to use a subquery to achieve that.

Comment: Alright, that `UPDATE .. JOIN` syntax is not supported in Oracle. Moreover, I actually don't see any issue in OP's posted update query except that his ON clause is bit ODD and he supposed to use a AFTER trigger whereas he is using a BEFORE trigger.